# using 2 wireless routers to connect to 1 internet connection

Tags: networking, router, wifi

I have 8 computers and two 4 port wireless routers. I want to be able to have all the computers to be connected via eithernet.1 router will be in one room with a cable modem  with 4 computers connected. The other will be in another room with 4 computers & no modem. how can I get the router without a modem connect wirelessly to the other router so I can get internet in the other room?

Answer (score 2):

1. Plug the second router into the first with an Ethernet cable, connected to LAN on both ends, **not** WAN (that's connected to the cable modem only).
2. If one of the WAPs supports Bridge/Repeater/Mesh mode, use that to connect it to the first. This will be less reliable than #1

Disable DHCP on the 2nd WAP.